# How do I detect a max. recursion depth exceeded exception in Python?

Tags: python

```
try:
    recursive_function()
except RuntimeError e:
    # is this a max. recursion depth exceeded exception?
```

How do I tell when the maximum recursion depth has been reached?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look inside the exception itself:

```
>>> def f():
...     f()
... 
>>> try:
...     f()
... except RuntimeError as re:
...     print re.args, re.message
... 
('maximum recursion depth exceeded',) maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I don't think you can distinguish between this and something merely pretending to be a recursion-depth-exceeded (Runtime) exception, though.  `message` is deprecated, so `args` is probably the best bet, and is Python-3 compatible.

---

Update: in Python 3.5, there's a specific `RecursionError` which you can catch instead.